# Creating a transition between two WPF gradients on a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this button:

[image]

which is made of this XAML code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="GreenButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#446c06" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#55ffffff" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Padding="6,4">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="contentShadow" Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="1.0" Y="1.0" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#aae64b" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="0.16"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#6aa016" Offset="0.57"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#649714" Offset="0.86"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#bbf75c" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#8fba33" Offset="0.16"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7bb127" Offset="0.57"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#75a825" Offset="0.86"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#8fca33" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#aae64b" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="0.16"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#6aa016" Offset="0.57"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#649714" Offset="0.86"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter TargetName="content" Property="RenderTransform" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TranslateTransform Y="1.0" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Everything is OK, except that I want to have a transition/animation between the mouse states (pressed + normal + hover).

I've found some guides online where they animate every gradient stop property, but I don't want to do that. I simply want to have a direct transition between the gradients.

Is there a simply way to do this without animating every single gradient stop property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Erno there is no `LinearGradientAnimation` but it can be created in just the same way as `ColorAnimation` works. If we look at the implementation of `ColorAnimation` we find that it uses helper functions like

- `AddColor(Color value1, Color value2)`
- `SubtractColor(Color value1, Color value2)`
- `ScaleColor(Color value, double factor)`
- `InterpolateColor(Color from, Color to, double progress)`

To create a `LinearGradientAnimation` we need the same functions but for `LinearGradientBrush` instead of `Color`. I created such an animation and it seems to work as expected. One requirement is that both the `To` and `From` value have the same number of `GradientStops`.

It's usable like this

```
<Storyboard>
    <ani:LinearGradientAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                 Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                 From="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                                 To="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
</Storyboard>
```

And in your case it will be something like this..

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#aae64b" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="0.16"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#6aa016" Offset="0.57"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#649714" Offset="0.86"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#bbf75c" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#8fba33" Offset="0.16"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#7bb127" Offset="0.57"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#75a825" Offset="0.86"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#8fca33" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0" >
    <GradientStop Color="#aae64b" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="0.16"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#6aa016" Offset="0.57"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#649714" Offset="0.86"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#7eb922" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="GreenButtonStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}"               
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#446c06" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#55ffffff" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Padding="6,4">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="contentShadow">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="1.0" Y="1.0" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ani:LinearGradientAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                                                    Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                    To="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="mouseUpStoryboard"/>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="mouseLeaveStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ani:LinearGradientAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                                                    Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                    To="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ani:LinearGradientAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                To="{StaticResource PressedBrush}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="mouseUpStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ani:LinearGradientAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                To="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Setter TargetName="content" Property="RenderTransform" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TranslateTransform Y="1.0" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Uploaded a small sample application with `LinearGradientAnimation` here: [LinearGradientAnimationDemo.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ngd2p4ezo6x6ec/LinearGradientAnimationDemo.zip?dl=0)

*LinearGradientAnimation.cs*

```
public class LinearGradientAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{
    #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("From",
                                     typeof(LinearGradientBrush),
                                     typeof(LinearGradientAnimation),
                                     new PropertyMetadata(null, AnimationFunction_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("To",
                                    typeof(LinearGradientBrush),
                                    typeof(LinearGradientAnimation),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(null, AnimationFunction_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ByProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("By",
                                    typeof(LinearGradientBrush),
                                    typeof(LinearGradientAnimation),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(null, AnimationFunction_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EasingFunctionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EasingFunction",
                                    typeof(IEasingFunction),
                                    typeof(LinearGradientAnimation));

    private static void AnimationFunction_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LinearGradientAnimation linearGradientAnimation = (LinearGradientAnimation)d;
        linearGradientAnimation._isAnimationFunctionValid = false;
    }

    #endregion // Dependency Properties

    #region Private Fields

    private LinearGradientBrush[] _keyValues;
    private AnimationType _animationType;
    private bool _isAnimationFunctionValid;

    #endregion // Private Fields

    #region Constructor

    public LinearGradientAnimation()
    {
    }

    public LinearGradientAnimation(LinearGradientBrush toValue, Duration duration)
        : this()
    {
        this.To = toValue;
        base.Duration = duration;
    }

    public LinearGradientAnimation(LinearGradientBrush toValue, Duration duration, FillBehavior fillBehavior)
        : this()
    {
        this.To = toValue;
        base.Duration = duration;
        base.FillBehavior = fillBehavior;
    }

    public LinearGradientAnimation(LinearGradientBrush fromValue, LinearGradientBrush toValue, Duration duration)
        : this()
    {
        this.From = fromValue;
        this.To = toValue;
        base.Duration = duration;
    }

    public LinearGradientAnimation(LinearGradientBrush fromValue, LinearGradientBrush toValue, Duration duration, FillBehavior fillBehavior)
        : this()
    {
        this.From = fromValue;
        this.To = toValue;
        base.Duration = duration;
        base.FillBehavior = fillBehavior;
    }

    #endregion // Constructor

    #region Properties

    public LinearGradientBrush From
    {
        get { return (LinearGradientBrush)base.GetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.FromProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.FromProperty, value); }
    }

    public LinearGradientBrush To
    {
        get { return (LinearGradientBrush)base.GetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.ToProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.ToProperty, value); }
    }

    public LinearGradientBrush By
    {
        get { return (LinearGradientBrush)base.GetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.ByProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.ByProperty, value); }
    }

    public IEasingFunction EasingFunction
    {
        get { return (IEasingFunction)base.GetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.EasingFunctionProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(LinearGradientAnimation.EasingFunctionProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool IsAdditive
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(AnimationTimeline.IsAdditiveProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(AnimationTimeline.IsAdditiveProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool IsCumulative
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(AnimationTimeline.IsCumulativeProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(AnimationTimeline.IsCumulativeProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion // Properties

    #region Private Methods

    protected LinearGradientBrush GetCurrentValueCore(LinearGradientBrush defaultOriginValue, LinearGradientBrush defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        if (!this._isAnimationFunctionValid)
        {
            this.ValidateAnimationFunction();
        }
        double num = animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value;
        IEasingFunction easingFunction = this.EasingFunction;
        if (easingFunction != null)
        {
            num = easingFunction.Ease(num);
        }
        LinearGradientBrush brush = null;
        LinearGradientBrush brush2 = null;
        LinearGradientBrush value = null;
        LinearGradientBrush value2 = null;
        switch (this._animationType)
        {
        case AnimationType.Automatic:
            brush = defaultOriginValue;
            brush2 = defaultDestinationValue;
            value = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            value2 = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            break;
        case AnimationType.From:
            brush = this._keyValues[0];
            brush2 = defaultDestinationValue;
            value = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            value2 = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            break;
        case AnimationType.To:
            brush = defaultOriginValue;
            brush2 = this._keyValues[0];
            value = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush2);
            value2 = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush2);
            break;
        case AnimationType.By:
            brush2 = this._keyValues[0];
            value2 = defaultOriginValue;
            value = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush2);
            value2 = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush2);
            break;
        case AnimationType.FromTo:
            brush = this._keyValues[0];
            brush2 = this._keyValues[1];
            value = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            value2 = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            if (this.IsAdditive)
            {
                value2 = defaultOriginValue;
            }
            break;
        case AnimationType.FromBy:
            brush = this._keyValues[0];
            brush2 = AddLinearGradientBrush(this._keyValues[0], this._keyValues[1]);
            value = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            value2 = GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(brush);
            if (this.IsAdditive)
            {
                value2 = defaultOriginValue;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (this.IsCumulative)
        {
            double num2 = (double)(animationClock.CurrentIteration - 1).Value;
            if (num2 > 0.0)
            {
                LinearGradientBrush value3 = SubtractLinearGradientBrush(brush2, brush);
                value = ScaleLinearGradientBrush(value3, num2);
            }
        }
        LinearGradientBrush returnBrush = AddLinearGradientBrush(value2, AddLinearGradientBrush(value, InterpolateGradientBrush(brush, brush2, num)));
        return returnBrush;
    }

    private LinearGradientBrush GetDefaultLinearGradientBrush(LinearGradientBrush brush)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush returnBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        returnBrush.StartPoint = default(Point);
        returnBrush.EndPoint = default(Point);
        for (int i = 0; i < brush.GradientStops.Count; i++)
        {
            returnBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(default(Color), default(double)));
        }
        return returnBrush;
    }

    private void ValidateAnimationFunction()
    {
        this._animationType = AnimationType.Automatic;
        this._keyValues = null;
        if (this.From != null)
        {
            if (this.To != null)
            {
                this._animationType = AnimationType.FromTo;
                this._keyValues = new LinearGradientBrush[2];
                this._keyValues[0] = this.From;
                this._keyValues[1] = this.To;
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.By != null)
                {
                    this._animationType = AnimationType.FromBy;
                    this._keyValues = new LinearGradientBrush[2];
                    this._keyValues[0] = this.From;
                    this._keyValues[1] = this.By;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._animationType = AnimationType.From;
                    this._keyValues = new LinearGradientBrush[1];
                    this._keyValues[0] = this.From;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.To != null)
            {
                this._animationType = AnimationType.To;
                this._keyValues = new LinearGradientBrush[1];
                this._keyValues[0] = this.To;
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.By != null)
                {
                    this._animationType = AnimationType.By;
                    this._keyValues = new LinearGradientBrush[1];
                    this._keyValues[0] = this.By;
                }
            }
        }
        this._isAnimationFunctionValid = true;
    }

    #endregion // Private Methods

    #region AnimationTimeline / Freezable Members

    public override Type TargetPropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(LinearGradientBrush); }
    }

    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        if (defaultOriginValue == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("defaultOriginValue");
        }
        if (defaultDestinationValue == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("defaultDestinationValue");
        }
        return this.GetCurrentValue((LinearGradientBrush)defaultOriginValue, (LinearGradientBrush)defaultDestinationValue, animationClock);
    }

    public LinearGradientBrush GetCurrentValue(LinearGradientBrush defaultOriginValue, LinearGradientBrush defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        base.ReadPreamble();
        if (animationClock == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("animationClock");
        }
        if (animationClock.CurrentState == ClockState.Stopped)
        {
            return defaultDestinationValue;
        }
        return this.GetCurrentValueCore(defaultOriginValue, defaultDestinationValue, animationClock);
    }

    public new LinearGradientAnimation Clone()
    {
        return (LinearGradientAnimation)base.Clone();
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new LinearGradientAnimation();
    }

    #endregion // AnimationTimeline / Freezable Members

    #region Helper Methods

    internal static LinearGradientBrush AddLinearGradientBrush(LinearGradientBrush brush1, LinearGradientBrush brush2)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        gradientBrush.StartPoint = AddPoint(brush1.StartPoint, brush2.StartPoint);
        gradientBrush.EndPoint = AddPoint(brush1.EndPoint, brush2.EndPoint);
        for (int i = 0; i < brush1.GradientStops.Count; i++)
        {
            GradientStop gradientStop1 = brush1.GradientStops[i];
            GradientStop gradientStop2 = brush2.GradientStops[i];

            Color color = AddColor(gradientStop1.Color, gradientStop2.Color);
            double offset = AddDouble(gradientStop1.Offset, gradientStop2.Offset);

            gradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(color, offset));
        }
        return gradientBrush;
    }
    internal static LinearGradientBrush SubtractLinearGradientBrush(LinearGradientBrush brush1, LinearGradientBrush brush2)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        gradientBrush.StartPoint = SubtractPoint(brush1.StartPoint, brush2.StartPoint);
        gradientBrush.EndPoint = SubtractPoint(brush1.EndPoint, brush2.EndPoint);
        for (int i = 0; i < brush1.GradientStops.Count; i++)
        {
            GradientStop gradientStop1 = brush1.GradientStops[i];
            GradientStop gradientStop2 = brush2.GradientStops[i];

            Color color = SubtractColor(gradientStop1.Color, gradientStop2.Color);
            double offset = SubtractDouble(gradientStop1.Offset, gradientStop2.Offset);

            gradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(color, offset));
        }
        return gradientBrush;
    }
    internal static LinearGradientBrush ScaleLinearGradientBrush(LinearGradientBrush value, double factor)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        gradientBrush.StartPoint = ScalePoint(value.StartPoint, factor);
        gradientBrush.EndPoint = ScalePoint(value.EndPoint, factor);
        for (int i = 0; i < value.GradientStops.Count; i++)
        {
            Color color = ScaleColor(value.GradientStops[i].Color, factor);
            double offset = ScaleDouble(value.GradientStops[i].Offset, factor);
            gradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(color, offset));
        }
        return gradientBrush;
    }
    internal static LinearGradientBrush InterpolateGradientBrush(LinearGradientBrush from, LinearGradientBrush to, double progress)
    {
        LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
        gradientBrush.StartPoint = InterpolatePoint(from.StartPoint, to.StartPoint, progress);
        gradientBrush.EndPoint = InterpolatePoint(from.EndPoint, to.EndPoint, progress);
        for (int i = 0; i < from.GradientStops.Count; i++)
        {
            Color color = InterpolateColor(from.GradientStops[i].Color, to.GradientStops[i].Color, progress);
            double offset = InterpolateDouble(from.GradientStops[i].Offset, to.GradientStops[i].Offset, progress);
            gradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(color, offset));
        }
        return gradientBrush;
    }
    internal static Color AddColor(Color value1, Color value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
    internal static Color SubtractColor(Color value1, Color value2)
    {
        return value1 - value2;
    }
    internal static Color ScaleColor(Color value, double factor)
    {
        return value * (float)factor;
    }
    internal static Color InterpolateColor(Color from, Color to, double progress)
    {
        return from + (to - from) * (float)progress;
    }

    internal static double AddDouble(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
    internal static double SubtractDouble(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1 - value2;
    }
    internal static double ScaleDouble(double value, double factor)
    {
        return value * factor;
    }
    internal static double InterpolateDouble(double from, double to, double progress)
    {
        return from + (to - from) * progress;
    }

    internal static Point AddPoint(Point value1, Point value2)
    {
        return new Point(value1.X + value2.X, value1.Y + value2.Y);
    }
    internal static Point SubtractPoint(Point value1, Point value2)
    {
        return new Point(value1.X - value2.X, value1.Y - value2.Y);
    }
    internal static Point ScalePoint(Point value, double factor)
    {
        return new Point(value.X * factor, value.Y * factor);
    }
    internal static Point InterpolatePoint(Point from, Point to, double progress)
    {
        return from + (to - from) * progress;
    }

    #endregion // Helper Methods
}
```

And you'll also need

```
internal enum AnimationType : byte
{
    Automatic,
    From,
    To,
    By,
    FromTo,
    FromBy
}
```

Comment: Nice example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could overlay two rectangles, each filled with a gradient and animate the opacity of the top rectangle.

This might look good or not depending on what you expect from the transition.

And if you are feeling adventurous: there is no LinearGradientAnimation but you could make it...